# Tabla con la función Seno

Tags: python, python-requests

Básicamente necesito un programa que muestre por pantalla una tabla con los valores correspondientes al seno desde 0 grados hasta 9 veces un valor incremento (expresado en grados) que se ingresa por teclado, considerando el valor del incremento ingresado siempre entero.

Hasta ahora solo llevo esto, y no estaría entendiendo como terminarlo o si está muy lejos de lo que debería ser:

```
from math import *

def func(x):
  sin(x)

def tabla(x):
  for i in range (0,90,10):
    sin(i)



g=int(raw_input(radians('g=')))

print 'Tabla de senos de 0 a 90'
print 'Grados  | Seno'
print '----------------------------'
print func(g),'     ' '|', tabla(g)
```

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esto:

```
from math import *

def tabla(x):
    for i in range (0,9):  #iteramos desde 1 a 9
        print str(i*x) + ' | ' + str(sin(i*x)) #anadimos el incremento

print 'Tabla de senos de 0 a 9*incremento' 
print 'Grados | Seno' 
print '----------------------------' 
tabla(90) #incremento de 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Le hice un par de correcciones, a mi me funciono.

```
from math import pi,sin

incremento = int(raw_input("Incremento: "))
print

def tabla(x):
    for incremento in range (0,10):
        print ("%2.1d %3.1s | %1.6f" %(incremento * x,"",sin(incremento * x 
        * pi / 180)))

    i = incremento*9

    print ("Tabla de senos de 0 a %2.1d" %i)
    print 'Grados | seno'
    print '-----------------'
    tabla(incremento)
```